# iPhone: How to remove glow (light) from UIBarButtonItem when pressed?

Tags: ios5, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm trying to remove the glow from a UIBarButton item so that my text appears to be a label instead of a button.  I've seen various posts talking about how to do this through interface builder or by setting a boolean variable "showsTouchWhenHighlighted", but neither of these options are available to me it appears. I've tried setting the showsTouchWhenHighlighted in the .m viewDidLoad where I change the font and font-size but the UIBarButtonItem doesn't appear to have that property.  I also only have the options in the following image to change in InterfaceBuilder.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do it with the standard bar button item. If you want to customize it to that level, you'd have to create a bar button item with a custom view that is actually a button configured the way you want (e.g., no glow) and add that instead of the standard items.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this (a bit of a hack but it works). Just drag a `UIButton` into your toolbar (instead of a `UIBarButtonItem`). Then a `UIBarButtonItem` will be automatically be created for you as a superview for your `UIButton`. Then you just set it like this:

**UIBarButtonItem**

- Style: Plain
- Title: (empty)

**UIButton**

- Type: Custom
- Title: (your actual label title here)
- Text Color: White
- Shows Touch On Highlight: (Unchecked)

Here is a screenshot to use as reference:
[image]

Note: Just remember that from now on any updates on the text must be made on the `UIButton`

Comment: When I try to click/drag the UIButton into the position of "Label" it throws it above my NavigationBar or puts it over my TableView completely. Something I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: From what I can see from your screenshot you appear to be working on a `UITableViewController`. That is not a good idea if you want several elements on your screen. I would recommend you to work on a `UIViewController` (that conforms to the appropriate protocols) and add a `UITableView` and a `UIToolbar` or whatever subview that you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140 , 0, 50, 250)];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    label.text = @"TEXT";
    UIView *view = (UIView *) label;
    [self.barItem setCustomView:view];
```

`

note: self.barItem is a UIBarButtonItem added from the object library and placed between two flexible spaces.

another way is to remove the `[self.barItem setCustom:view]` line and change the parameters of the label (width) so that it fills the entire toolbar and set the alignment to middle and the font by yourself in code,